# Python pandas read_csv issue with bad data when dtype is specified

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

I am reading a .csv file from amazon s3 bucket by using pandas 'read_csv'.  Below is the statement which I issued:

```
xyz = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), dtype={'col1': str ,'col2':int,'col3':int ,'col4':int} ,encoding='latin-1')
```

Now herein lies my problem; col2 contains some special characters such as " `" and col3 contains " : ". So is there a way in python wherein I can redirect these bad rows in a temp list by scanning all records from the .csv file on S3 bucket? I want to keep a log of bad data and insert the corrected one's only.

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should be aware that pandas allows you to read directly from S3 with something like

```
xyz = pd.read_csv('s3://bucket/file.csv, dtype={..}, encoding='latin-1')
```

however, this does not solve your bad-data problem. Using the python parser engine of regex delimiters *might* save you, but seems unlikely.

The simplest thing to do would be to download the file line-wise and put the bad lines in another output

```
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
with s3.open('bucket/file.csv', 'rb') as fin:
    with open('out_good.csv', 'wb') as fgood:
        with open('out_bad.csv', 'wb') as fbad:
            for line in fin:
                if ':' in line or '`' in line:
                    fbad.write(line)
                else:
                    fgood.write(line)
```

The alternative would be to write your own file-like object to read lines, do text decoding and provide read()/readline() methods for pandas to work one (I think it also needs things like readable(), etc).

Comment: Note that s3fs does not support text-mode directly, although it should; you could always use `io.TextIOWrapper`.

Comment: But the problem is we can't predict what these bad characters are; it could be anything (Eg: !,@,#). Is there a way wherein I can resolve this without hardcoding these bad characters in my script?                                              
                                                                                                                      Thanks.

Comment: The only way to know if a line will be parsed without errors by `read_csv` is to try.

Comment: No it doesn't work. The moment a bad character in the form of ':' or '`' is encountered; the program terminates and it doesn't read the other records.

Comment: Have your used try/except??

Comment: Yes I have tried try/except and the program terminates once bad character is encountered and it doesn't iterate to process the remaining records.

Comment: That doesn't sound likely - you should show your code, perhaps in a new question. Nevertheless, the answer above does meet the requirements of the question as it was originally posed.